# Java: typecasting an object to different non related object

Tags: java, android

I am studying the ksoap2-android project and I reached a confusing point

in the code below how is bodyOut of the type `org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject` is being typecasted to `org.kxml2.kdom.Node` object? while the two are not related in any way.

In the app I declared the following:

```
SoapObject soapRequest = new SoapObject()
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope()
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(soapRequest);
```

and in `class SoapSerializationEnvelope {}` we have:

```
public void setOutputSoapObject(Object soapObject) {
   this.bodyOut = soapObject;}

public void writeBody(XmlSerializer writer) throws IOException {
   if (encodingStyle != null) {
       writer.attribute(env, "encodingStyle", encodingStyle);
   }
((Node) this.bodyOut).write(writer);}
```

and we have the other class in a different package which is `Node`

```
public class Node {}
```

If the typecasting is depending on the root `class Object`, how is the relation instantiated between the two objects?

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint on that cast statement. See what type of object is in `bodyOut` and what its superclasses and implemented interfaces are.

Comment: Check if SoapObject extends Node directly or indirectly

Comment: They must be related in some way, otherwise the code would not compile. Look again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking at the source code of `writeBody` in `SoapEnvelope`.  The method is overridden in `SoapSerializationEnvelope` ... and *that* version doesn't cast the `bodyOut` object to a `Node`.

My analysis is based on these source links:

- https://github.com/simpligility/ksoap2-android/blob/master/ksoap2-base/src/main/java/org/ksoap2/SoapEnvelope.java
- https://github.com/simpligility/ksoap2-android/blob/master/ksoap2-base/src/main/java/org/ksoap2/serialization/SoapSerializationEnvelope.java

(At commit 82d9ac4c90bb818f9e8efe8049ca1978cd019d70.)

---

Having said that, the implementation of these methods in `SoapEnvelope` looks like it wouldn't work ... if you ever instantiated and tried to use `SoapEnvelope` rather than `SoapSerializationEnvelope`.

Comment: Doens'tr explain how the first code compiles. If it didn't compile, there would be no class and therefore no method for the second implementation to extend/override and it wouldn't compile either.

Comment: @EJP - `bodyOut` is declared as `Object` in `SoapEnvelope` ... where that `writeBody` method we are looking at is declared. Therefore `((Node) this.bodyOut)` compiles.

Comment: @EJP - look at the code in context via the links above.

Comment: @Stephen C, you are right on the spot. I missed that and now learned a lot about inheritance in java. thanks